# How to specify the installLocation in android 1.5 version?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-install-apk

I want to force my app to install in internal memory. I am using android version 1.5 to develop my application. In 1.5 there is no option for android:installLocation. How can i achieve that.

Comment: when my app install i need my app to installed in internal memory.@NikhilreddyGujjula

Comment: android:installLocation="preferExternal|auto"

Comment: that option is not there for android version1.5@NikhilreddyGujjula

Answer (score 0):

You can't. In 1.5 you can't install apps to the SDcard without a modified ROM. On those it's the user that chooses.

More info: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html